# Вычисление даты.

Tags: cron, php, mysql

Здравствуйте.

Решил сделать на сайте систему которая будет считать сколько времени прошло с публикации материала (Пример: 1 час назад , 2 часа назад , 1 день назад и тд). И вот встал вопрос как это можно реализовать? Пока есть варианты либо вычислять прямо на странице , либо сделать это все "кроном" который будет все это дело заносить в базу и потом просто выводить. Материалов довольно много. Как будет более эфективно и быстрее для работы сервера?

Заранее спасибо.

ps. Не против выслушать другие варианты как это можно сделать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

в таблице сделай поле timestamp  тип INTEGER.

Записывай туда дату ф-ей mktime()

ну и потом просто сравнивай, можешь даже посекундно выводить типа

> Изменено 1 минуту и 23 секунды назад.

или

> Изменено 1 год 3 месяца 4 дня 12 часов 5 минут 11 секунд назад

как хочешь.

Это в реальном времени будет считаться. А для того чтобы не грузить сервак, можно по крону запускать и страницу кешировать с результатом, или результат кешировать отдельно, хотя лучше конечно если контент не меняется то страницу целиком закешировать.

Answer (score 2):

В MySQL должно лежать поле с обычной датой-временем. Расчет времени, которое прошло с момента публикации, должен делать PHP в момент вывода страницы в браузер. Именно в этот момент информация актуальна. То-есть, использовать для этой задачи крон - бессмысленно.

Если нужен динамический счетчик, то это уже нужно делать на уровне JavaScript. PHP выводит на страницу время публикации, в браузере JavaScript его сразу читает и, например, раз в секунду делает расчет и вывод нового значения.

Итого: нагрузка на сервер стремится к нулю (разовый расчет в момент вывода).